# How to display a child div BEFORE the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements, and I want the third one to display before the previous 2. The third is also an image, and the height vary from each content.

The structure I have is:

```
<div class="first">
 ..
</div>

<ul>
 <li>..</li>
</ul>

<div class="image">
</div>
```

How can I display the image before the first div with css? If not possible with this config, I can also create a new div for the ul, but only if not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to use the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) flex property:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.image {
  order:-3;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
 first
</div>

<ul>
 <li>li</li>
</ul>

<div class="image">image
</div>
```

Annex: [FlexBox compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Comment: F*ckin genius!! Thanks for the solution and the speed!

Comment: Is there a way to do that with older browsers, or kind of fallback css?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Nothing clean that I know. You could give fixed positions to items ([like this](http://jsbin.com/fabiwamiga/edit?html,css,output)) but this would be painful to maintain.

Comment: It's is available to 95% browsers using prefixes. I'm not sure If I should use it. What do you think?

Comment: There's so much sanity retrieved when forgetting IE9 that I don't hesitate. But for *your* sites, the choice isn't mine (BTW it's much more than 95% today).